# Draw canvas text with background image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to achieve this when drawing a canvas:

- First i draw an image as a background with canvas
- Then draw a text with the color of another image

=> The problem is the bg-image have been overlap by the text-img

This is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img1 = document.getElementById("bg-img");    
    var img2 = document.getElementById("text-img");

    // draw the first image as background
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

    // put text on canvas
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();   
    ctx.font = "50pt Verdana";
    ctx.fillText("XBOX", 10, 100);
    ctx.fill();
    // use compositing to draw the background image
    // only where the text has been drawn
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, img2.width, img2.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();
    
};
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>

<img id="bg-img" src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg" alt="">
<img id="text-img" src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg" alt="">

<p>Canvas:</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="297"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
```

Link for testing:
http://jsfiddle.net/1x5dfgty/14/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) in "destination-over" mode allows you to paint a background to your canvas:

```js
function onReady() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img1 = document.getElementById("bg-img");
    var img2 = document.getElementById("text-img");
    // draw the first image as background
    // uncomment this to see the problem
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    // put text on canvas
    ctx.font = "50pt Verdana";
    ctx.fillText("XBOX", 10, 100);
    ctx.fill();
    // use compositing to draw the background image
    // only where the text has been drawn
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, img2.width, img2.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    //ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, img1.width, img1.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Stretch to fit image
}
window.addEventListener("load", onReady);
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>

<img id="bg-img" src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg" alt="">
<img id="text-img" src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg" alt="">

<p>Canvas:</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="297"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
```